# how to deserealize JSON without field names

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, deserialization

I invoke a REST service that returns a JSON, I'm trying to deserialize it (convert it into an entity) but the thing is that it doesn't have field names to match.
The JSON is like this one:

```json
{
    "text1": "",
    "text2": null,
    "days": [
        {
            "20211217": {
                "07:00": {
                    "id": "1187067",
                    "cupo": 9
                },
                "08:00": {
                    "id": "1187068",
                    "cupo": 10
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "20211219": {
                "07:00": {
                    "id": "1187077",
                    "cupo": 10
                },
                "08:00": {
                    "id": "1187078",
                    "cupo": 10
                }
            
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you could see it have some fields like text1, text2, days, id and cupo, the problem is how to map the date text (20211217,20211219) and hours text. How could I manipulate this data?

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: put it into a map

Comment: Are you using any libraries like Gson or Jackson?

Comment: im using jackson. Maybe I didnt explain it well, those dates and hour field are random. I want to put that data in an entity that have a date field and a list with hour, id and cupo

Comment: Just do it yourself. Load up the JSON, iterate across the raw result, and stuff the appropriate bits in to the appropriate places. You can likely do this far faster than beating some framework in to submission to "do it for you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could model the JSON as follows:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class YourClass {
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    private List<Map<String, Map<String, YourOtherClass>>> days;

    public YourClass(String text1, String text2, List<Map<String, Map<String, YourOtherClass>>> days) {
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
        this.days = days;
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1;
    }

    public void setText1(String text1) {
        this.text1 = text1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return text2;
    }

    public void setText2(String text2) {
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Map<String, YourOtherClass>>> getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(List<Map<String, Map<String, YourOtherClass>>> days) {
        this.days = days;
    }
}
```

And then the other class to model `id` and `cupo` as follows:

```java
public class YourOtherClass {
    private String id;
    private int cupo;

    public YourOtherClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCupo() {
        return cupo;
    }

    public void setCupo(int cupo) {
        this.cupo = cupo;
    }
}
```